# Does the Democratic Progressive Party plan to modify the founding ideology of the Republic of China?

Tags: constitution, taiwan

The Democratic Progressive Party  of the Republic of China (aka Taiwan) aims at modifying the ROC's constitution.
See [here](https://focustaiwan.tw/politics/202309130017), and [here](https://www.dpp.org.tw/en/upload/download/Party_Platform.pdf).

Does this party plan to modify the first article of the constitution, which stipulates that the ROC is "founded on the Three Principles of the People" (i.e. Sun Yat-Sen nationalist ideology) ([here](https://english.president.gov.tw/Page/94))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The DPP, in the party platform you link to, proposes changing the name of the country (in article 1) from "Republic of China" to "Republic of Taiwan" (presumably 台灣共和國, but I'm no scholar of Chinese).

> Following the principle of popular sovereignty, we
> hereby propose that the decision for establishing
> the Republic of Taiwan as a sovereign state and
> formulating a new constitution should be made by
> the residents of Taiwan via referendum.

They don't propose a text for Article 1, but it would be surprising if it included "The three principles".  I note that they also propose reform of the college entrance system and scrapping the exam on the "Three principles".

They propose that these changes be made by referendum.

Comment: quote in Traditional Chinese: 基於國民主權原理，建立主權獨立自主的台灣共和國及制定新憲法的主張，應交由台灣全體住民以公民投票方式選擇決定。

Comment: qv. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46697/if-taiwan-declares-independence-would-that-mean-they-are-relinquishing-their-cl?rq=1

Comment: "but it would be surprising if it included "The three principles"" Maybe this answer could detail more why this should be surprising. It doesn't seem obvious at first glance. It's also the core of the question.

Comment: There are three reasons I'd be surprised.  1) There is no mention of retaining them.  2) They propose scrapping the college entrance test on the them.  The party indicates that it does not view these principles as fundamental or foundational 3) They are derived from the writings of Sun Yat-Sen of the Kuomintang - the party that the DPP is opposed to.

Comment: Dear James K. I think you grasped a very important information concerning the college entrance exam. About (3): Sun Yat-sen is considered as the founder of the Republic of China, aka Taiwan. So it would be an argument for retaining these "Three Principles", but at the same time also an argument to erase them, because precisely it seems the DPP wants to distance the island regime from the mainland history, something which is translated by them when they want to change the island regime from "Republic of China" to "Taiwan". But then it would be a quite groundbreaking move

Comment: I suppose the debates on the topic are very sensitive, so I wonder whether there is even public discussion on this or not from the DPP